# Socat hangs when piping stdin to tcp server

Tags: tcp, pipe, stdin, freeze, socat

I have an embedded linux system running a tcp server.
Telnet can connect to and use the tcp server interactively just fine.

I am trying to use socat to make the same connection, by linking stdin to the tcp server, like so:

`socat - tcp:localhost:8088`

I get the initial response from the server, and I can type, but as soon as I press enter, the terminal hangs (I can get out of this with Ctrl + C as long as I am not using the raw socat option.)

If I do the same thing but with readline, everything mostly works as expected:

`socat readline tcp:localhost:8088`

However, with readline, the terminal echoes my input, and then the response from the server also echoes it. This is more than just an annoyance, since things like passwords (which should not even be echoed once) are now visible.

Ideally, I would just use stdin instead of readline, so that I could send each character as soon as I type it, and turn off stdin echo. That way, when I type a character, the tcp server receives it and echoes it immediately, but only if it is supposed to.

But socat is hanging with the stdin option for reasons I don't understand.

I'm looking for an explanation as to why stdin is locking up the thread, or a workaround possibly using readline or similar.

EDIT: Here is the dddd debug output from the socat command when I use stdin:

> sh-5.0# socat -d -d -d -d -lu - tcp:localhost:8088
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.805536 socat[1074] D getpid()
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807631 socat[1074] D getpid() -> 1074
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807667 socat[1074] D setenv("SOCAT_PID", "1074",
> 1)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807687 socat[1074] D setenv() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807704 socat[1074] D setenv("SOCAT_PPID", "1074",
> 1)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807724 socat[1074] D setenv() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807737 socat[1074] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and
> contributors - see [www.dest-unreach.org](http://www.dest-unreach.org)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807752 socat[1074] I This product includes
> software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL
> Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807767 socat[1074] I This product includes
> software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807781 socat[1074] D socat version 1.7.3.3 on May
> 25 2021 13:47:29
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807795 socat[1074] D setenv("SOCAT_VERSION",
> "1.7.3.3", 1)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807811 socat[1074] D setenv() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807827 socat[1074] D running on Linux version #1
> SMP Mon Jan 31 20:48:32 UTC 2022, release 5.4.0, machine aarch64
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807845 socat[1074] D argv[0]: "socat"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807857 socat[1074] D argv[1]: "-d"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807870 socat[1074] D argv[2]: "-d"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807883 socat[1074] D argv[3]: "-d"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807895 socat[1074] D argv[4]: "-d"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807907 socat[1074] D argv[5]: "-lu"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807920 socat[1074] D argv[6]: "-"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807932 socat[1074] D argv[7]: "tcp:localhost:8088"
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807945 socat[1074] D sigaction(1, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807960 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807973 socat[1074] D sigaction(2, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.807987 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808000 socat[1074] D sigaction(3, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808014 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808026 socat[1074] D sigaction(4, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808040 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808053 socat[1074] D sigaction(6, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808067 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808079 socat[1074] D sigaction(7, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808092 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808105 socat[1074] D sigaction(8, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808119 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808132 socat[1074] D sigaction(11, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808146 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808158 socat[1074] D sigaction(15, 0xffffc8d63a18,
> 0x0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808172 socat[1074] D sigaction() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808185 socat[1074] D signal(13, 0x1)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808200 socat[1074] D signal() -> 0x0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808213 socat[1074] D atexit(0xaaaaba73c4a0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808226 socat[1074] D atexit() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808267 socat[1074] D calloc(1, 848)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808284 socat[1074] D calloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cc680
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808304 socat[1074] D malloc(1024)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808318 socat[1074] D malloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cca00
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808333 socat[1074] D calloc(1, 848)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808350 socat[1074] D calloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cce10
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808364 socat[1074] D calloc(1, 848)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808377 socat[1074] D calloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cd170
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808391 socat[1074] D isatty(0)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808411 socat[1074] D isatty() -> 1
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808424 socat[1074] D tcgetattr(0, 0xaaaadd2ccf6c)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808461 socat[1074] D tcgetattr(,
> {00005400,00000005,00001cb2,0000083b, 4098,4098,
> 03,1c,7f,15,04,00,01,00,11,13,1a,00,12,0f,17,16,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00})
> -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808480 socat[1074] D isatty(1)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808494 socat[1074] D isatty() -> 1
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808507 socat[1074] D tcgetattr(1, 0xaaaadd2cd2cc)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:58.808542 socat[1074] D tcgetattr(,
> {00005400,00000005,00001cb2,0000083b, 4098,4098,
> 03,1c,7f,15,04,00,01,00,11,13,1a,00,12,0f,17,16,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00})
> -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141868 socat[1074] D malloc(128)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141888 socat[1074] D malloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cd4d0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141903 socat[1074] D malloc(128)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141916 socat[1074] D malloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cd560
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141931 socat[1074] N reading from and writing to
> stdio
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141946 socat[1074] D calloc(1, 848)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141959 socat[1074] D calloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cd5f0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141983 socat[1074] D malloc(1024)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.141997 socat[1074] D malloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cd9b0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142015 socat[1074] D getaddrinfo("localhost",
> NULL, {1,0,1,6,0,0x0,0x0,0x0}, 0xffffc8d63538)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142789 socat[1074] D getaddrinfo(,,,{{AF=10
> [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001]:0, }) -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142815 socat[1074] D malloc(128)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142830 socat[1074] D malloc() -> 0xaaaadd2ce610
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142847 socat[1074] N opening connection to AF=2
> 127.0.0.1:8088
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142861 socat[1074] I starting connect loop
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142876 socat[1074] D socket(2, 1, 6)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142900 socat[1074] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142919 socat[1074] D fcntl(5, 2, 1)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142935 socat[1074] D fcntl() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.142954 socat[1074] D connect(5, {2,AF=2
> 127.0.0.1:8088}, 16)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145199 socat[1074] D connect() -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145246 socat[1074] D getsockname(5,
> 0xffffc8d635b8, 0xffffc8d6359c{112})
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145269 socat[1074] D getsockname(, {AF=2
> 127.0.0.1:46294}, {16}) -> 0
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145286 socat[1074] N successfully connected from
> local address AF=2 127.0.0.1:46294
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145306 socat[1074] I resolved and opened all sock
> addresses
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145321 socat[1074] D malloc(16385)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145344 socat[1074] D malloc() -> 0xaaaadd2cf400
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145360 socat[1074] N starting data transfer loop
> with FDs [0,1] and [5,5]
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145375 socat[1074] D data loop: sock1->eof=0,
> sock2->eof=0, closing=0, wasaction=1, total_to={0.000000}
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145395 socat[1074] D select(6, &0x21, &0x22, &0x0,
> NULL/0.000000)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145426 socat[1074] D select -> (, 0x0, 0x20, 0x0,
> NULL/0.000000), 1
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145443 socat[1074] D data loop: sock1->eof=0,
> sock2->eof=0, closing=0, wasaction=1, total_to={0.000000}
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.145461 socat[1074] D select(6, &0x21, &0x2, &0x0,
> NULL/0.000000)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.157132 socat[1074] D select -> (, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0,
> NULL/0.000000), 1
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.157178 socat[1074] D data loop: sock1->eof=0,
> sock2->eof=0, closing=0, wasaction=1, total_to={0.000000}
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.157198 socat[1074] D select(2, &0x1, &0x2, &0x0,
> NULL/0.000000)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401692 socat[1074] D select -> (, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0,
> NULL/0.000000), 1
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401732 socat[1074] D read(5, 0xaaaadd2cf400, 8192)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401765 socat[1074] D read -> 48
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401782 socat[1074] D write(1, 0xaaaadd2cf400, 48)
>
> ÿûÿû
>
> Connect to IP address 169.254.12.16
>
> > 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401809 socat[1074] D write -> 48
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401823 socat[1074] I transferred 48 bytes from 5
> to 1
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401838 socat[1074] D data loop: sock1->eof=0,
> sock2->eof=0, closing=0, wasaction=1, total_to={0.000000}
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.401856 socat[1074] D select(6, &0x21, &0x2, &0x0,
> NULL/0.000000)
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.462969 socat[1074] D select -> (, 0x0, 0x2, 0x0,
> NULL/0.000000), 1
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.463017 socat[1074] D data loop: sock1->eof=0,
> sock2->eof=0, closing=0, wasaction=1, total_to={0.000000}
>
> 2022/02/04 01:34:59.463036 socat[1074] D select(6, &0x21, &0x0, &0x0,
> NULL/0.000000)

At this point, I can still type, but no matter what I do, I get nothing in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a combination of things.

1. The version of socat I was using (1.7.3.3) has a bug when using certain options. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/socat/+bug/1883957 for more info.
2. The tty options in my terminal were atypical somehow. By using "stty sane", and then adding -brkint, I got the entire thing working with stdin.

My final solution uses socat version 1.7.4.3, and looks like this:

```
stty sane

stty -brkint -icanon && socat -,echo=0 tcp:localhost:8088
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not Socat that hangs but the server. Use options -v -x to see what data Socat transfers in both situations and compare; maybe there are different line termination characters involved.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. The reason I assumed it was not the server is because the server code has not changed, and this used to work on an older version of linux.

I have noticed that when I pipe data to socat through stdin, like so: 
echo "some command" | socat - tcp:localhost:8088
...I get the proper response, followed by unlimited newlines

Comment: The data looks almost identical in both cases when first connecting. I cannot see any debug data from stdin once I get it to freeze, it just freezes in the same way as before when I press enter. I can add the data comparison from the initial connection to my question

Comment: So, please add options -d -d -d -d -lu to see where and when Socat appears to stop working!